# Wrap google ads around the box

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Could you please help me to draw a box around google ads, which i am displaying on my wordpress website. Width should be 100% and height should be according to ads (with few padding) and a small tag "Advertisement" at top left side.

I will be very thankful. You can see a sample image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="add-wrapper"> 
   Your Google Code
</div>
```

CSS should be following:

```
.add-wrapper::before {
  color: #a3a3a3;
  content: "Advertisement";
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 150px;
  left: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: -2px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 130px;
}

.add-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  min-height: 145px;
  margin: 35px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Thats it

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. But unfortunately its not working. I placed those codes inside the CSS file and following code inside the post.. but i only see plain add no border around that. 

<div class="add-wrapper"> 
   Your Google Code
</div>

Comment: what is the result its showing, can you share JSfiddle of your code or link to review?

Comment: On this place where you have "Test Google ad" add that box?

Comment: I have added that Sanjeev, inside the post "Test Google Ad" code is as follows

<div class="add-wrapper">

<script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" async=""></script>
 <!-- mcmc-middle-post -->
 <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-4149412916113541" data-ad-slot="9301072714" data-ad-format="rectangle"></ins>
<script>// <![CDATA[
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
// ]]></script>

</div>

Comment: You have actually not added the code which I have update above, update the CSS

Comment: Thanks Sanjeev, Its little better now. If you check the link http://amexing.in/index.php/2016/07/07/test-google-ad/

Advertisement is still inside the box but it should be outside as per the same image i uploaded earlier.

Thanks for your help

Comment: @AvinashPatel I have updated the CSS above in answer, replace it with existing version.

Comment: Thanks Sanjeev, I have slightly modified the CSS and the page is looking like this http://amexing.in/index.php/2016/07/07/test-google-ad/

I just wonder why are there too much white space inside the box... we we can minimize that to 2px top and bottom that will be great.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have updated the CSS above in my answer, just copy the css of .add-wrapper::before and replace with the existing version in your html

Comment: I replaced the code but still there are white space (top and down) if you look into the sample image i uploaded there are very little padding (top and bottom)

You can check here http://amexing.in/index.php/2016/07/07/test-google-ad/

Comment: Hi Anyone,

Could you please help here to reduce the space around google ads